# Kubernetes error building cluster, utility subnet can't be found

Tags: kubernetes, subnet, utility

Why is it that when I try to update a new Kubernetes cluster it gives the following error:

```
$ kops update cluster --name k8s-web-dev
   error building tasks: could not find utility subnet in zone: "us-east-1b"
```

I have not been able to deploy it into aws yet. It only creates configs inside s3.

Also because I have private and public subnets I am updating manually k8s config to point to correct subnet-ids. e.g: The ids were added manually.

`subnets:
  - cidr: 10.0.0.0/19
    id: subnet-3724bb40 
    name: us-east-1b
    type: Private
    zone: us-east-1b
  - cidr: 10.0.64.0/19
    id: subnet-918a35c8
    name: us-east-1c
    type: Private
    zone: us-east-1c
  - cidr: 10.0.32.0/20
    id: subnet-4824bb3f
    name: utility-us-east-1b
    type: Public
    zone: us-east-1b
  - cidr: 10.0.96.0/20
    id: subnet-908a35c9
    name: utility-us-east-1c
    type: Public
    zone: us-east-1c`

Also interestingly enough I did no change in my config. But when I run the kops update once and then once more I get two different results. How is that possible?

`kops update cluster --name $n
  error building tasks: could not find utility subnet in zone: "us-east-1c"`

and then this

`kops update cluster --name $n
  error building tasks: could not find utility subnet in zone: "us-east-1b"`

Comment: Maybe u need to update ur kops version https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1147

Comment: @Ura718, Can you provide `kops version`?

Comment: My kops version is: 
Version 1.8.1 (git-94ef202)

Comment: So it looks like was able to resolve the problem. The issue stemmed from trying to build a cluster with a bastion host (e.g: --bastion) within the kops create cluster parameter options. I excluded the bastion host option and built the cluster only with master/nodes. That seemed to fix the problem. I'm guessing that if you try to build the cluster with --bastion option it wont find the custom public utility subnet id. I dont know why... But in any case without the bastion host option the cluster build worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--bastion` parameter within `kops` command line options assumes that bastion instance group is already in place. To create bastion instance group you can use `--role` flag:

`kops create instancegroup bastions --role Bastion --subnet $SUBNET`

Check this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/bastion.md) for more information.